# Recycler view refresh not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am retrieving data from mysqli database into android recycler view through volley string request. I want the recycler view to refresh when ever an item Is added without having to do a manual refresh. I added the notifyDataSetChanged to the main activity's on create method but when ever an item Is added the recycler view doesn't refresh. Below is my code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        RecyclerLayout adapter;
        List <Recycler> arrayList;
        private static final String url = "http://example.com";

    @Override 
     //overriding the onCreate method from its super class
    {
        recyclerView = findViewById (R.id.recycler);
        arrayList = new ArrayList <>();
        retrieveData ();

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize (true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager (this));
        adapter = new adapter(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter (adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
        }

        private void retrieveData (){
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StingRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
            new Response.Listener <String>();
            @Override 
            public void onResponseListener (response){

            //surround jsonArray with try and catch
                JsonArray array = new JsonArray  (response);

                for (int i = o;  i  < array.length (); i++){
                    JsonObject object = array.getJsonObject(i) ;
                     arrayList.add (new Recycler (
                      object.getString ("text")))
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener <>()
            /**overriding the error listener method**/);
            //adding the volley request on a queue 
        }
    }


    //Recycler adapter class

    public class RecyclerLayout extends RecyclerView.adapter <RecyclerLayout.RecyclerHolder>{
            Context ctx;
            List <Recycler> arrayList;
        RecyclerLayout(Context ctx, List <Recycler> arrayList){
                this.ctx=ctx;
                this.arrayList = arrayList;
            }
            @Override 
            //creating the view

            @Override 
             //implementing the onBind method

            @Override 
             //implementing the getItemCount method
        RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        }
    }


    //Recycler j son store
    public class Recycler {
            private String text;
        Recycler (String text){
            this.text = text;
        }
        public String getText (){
            return text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call notifyDataSetChanged after item is retrieved and added to an array. Calling notifyDataSetChanged after setAdapter is pointless, since at this point adapter does not need to update.

Answer (score 0):

change code from

```
 adapter = new adapter(getApplicationContext())  
 recyclerView.setAdapter (adapter);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
```

to

```
adapter = new RecyclerLayout(getApplicationContext(),arrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter (adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code should give you error. You should modify your code as below. In `onCreate()`:

```
 recyclerView = findViewById (R.id.recycler);
 arrayList = new ArrayList <>();
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize (true);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager (this));
 adapter = new adapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);
 recyclerView.setAdapter (adapter);
```

In `retriveData()` method:

```
 public void onResponseListener (response){

        //surround jsonArray with try and catch
            JsonArray array = new JsonArray  (response);

        for (int i = o;  i  < array.length (); i++){
                JsonObject object = array.getJsonObject(i) ;
                 arrayList.add (new Recycler (
                  object.getString ("text")))
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```